# ConText: Text overflow over into the footer

Tags: context

In the MWE the text overflows into the footerdistance and into the footer. Why is this happening and how can I avoid it? The documents are generated and very long.

The `split` at `placetable` seems to be the cause for the overflow. Is there a other way to split tables over multiple pages?

updated MWE:

```
\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}]


\showframe

\starttext


\externalfigure[cow][scale=600]

\emptylines[26]


\placetable[here,split]
   []
   {}  {
\startxtable
  \startxtablehead
    \startxrow
      \startxcell text  \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtablehead
  \startxtablebody
    \startxrow
      \startxcell text \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtablebody
\stopxtable
}
Text

overflowing text into the footer, overflowing text into the footer

\stoptext
```

Comment: If you want more control over the layout use `\definemeasure` to set the values but don’t use `topspace` etc. to set the main values for the layout. The first big problem in your document is the missing brace for the first float, another is the `split` option because the float can’t be splitted. To create dummy lines you can use the `\emptylines[<NUMBER>]` command.

Comment: The first brace is wrong. I must have overlooked it when creating the mwe. The `split` is necessary, otherwise the table cannot be split over multiple pages. I minified the mwe further. The split attribute seems to play a big role.

Comment: can you provide a complete MWE that compiles and produces the undesired result?

Comment: @FLonLon The MWE compiles flawlessly and shows the result. Please note that this is ConTeXt and not LaTeX.

Comment: @TeXnician oh- my bad!

Comment: Crosspost: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/093298.html