# ConTeXt: Use of t-vim module in table

Tags: context, t-vim

How can use the t-vim module inside a TABLE environment?

I know it propably has something to do with buffers but I'm not sure how to store the output from vim into a buffer.

MWE:

```
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping
  [somecode]
  [lines=split]

\starttext
\typebuffer[visit]

\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD 
\startsomecode
test code
\stopsomecode
        \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

Comment: I realized that `process<vim>buffer` was not documented, so I added it to the documentation at [github](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/vim-README.md)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `t-vim` is built on top of `t-filter`, you can can use the `\process<filter>buffer` command to load an existing buffer:

```
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping
  [somecode]
  [lines=split]

\definevimtyping
  [RUBY]
  [syntax=ruby]

\starttext

\startbuffer[ruby]
# Ruby program listing
print("Hello World")
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[somecode]
test code
more lines
\stopbuffer

\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD
          \processsomecodebuffer[somecode]
        \eTD
        \bTD
          \processRUBYbuffer[ruby]
        \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

You could alternatively use the module `ntb-to-xtb`, which lets you use xtables with natural table syntax (in other words: this lets you use TeXnicians solution *without* changing the code):

```
\usemodule[vim]
\usemodule[ntb-to-xtb]

\definevimtyping
  [somecode]
  [lines=split]

\definevimtyping
  [RUBY]
  [syntax=ruby]

\starttext

\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD
\startsomecode
test code
more lines
\stopsomecode
        \eTD
        \bTD
\startRUBY
# Ruby program listing
print("Hello World")
\stopRUBY
        \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

The output for both solutions is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

More of a comment than an answer: With xtables you may use verbatim material directly.

```
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping
  [somecode]
  [lines=split]

\starttext
\typebuffer[visit]

\startxtable
    \startxrow
        \startxcell 
\startsomecode
test code
\stopsomecode
        \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

Comment: I had to move away from xtables because I encountered problems with them... 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460142/context-text-overflow-over-into-the-footer and https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/093357.html

Comment: @ChristopherBock Ah, okay. Then this answer is just for future readers who might not have problems with xtables.